# Excel button to find product and change stock to 0 or 50

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

For our eCommerce business we have a large spreadsheet which we use to manage stock and sync to our website. At the moment it's a completely manual process.

I'm wondering how I could add two buttons to do the below..

Product examples..

```
Column A             |  Column B
Product Name         |  Stock
---------------------+--------------
Product1_Variation1  |  50
Product1_Variation2  |  50
Product1_Variation3  |  50
Product1_Variation4  |  50
Product2_Variation1  |  50
Product2_Variation2  |  50
Product2_Variation3  |  50
Product2_Variation4  |  50
```

In another column I would enter the product I want to update, IE in column D1 I type Product1. There is then two buttons...

Out of Stock - would search for all products in column A where the text contains Product1 (in D1) and changes the stock to 0.

In Stock - would search for all product in column A where the text contains Product1 (in D1) and changes the stock to 50.

**I'm aware this would need some VB code which is where I would struggle.**

**EDIT**

```
Sub button_1_oos_aw()
    change_stock Range("B2").Text, Range("B3").Text, 0, Range("N2").Text, "OOS", Range("L2").Text
End Sub

Sub button_1_bis_aw()
    change_stock Range("B2").Text, Range("B3").Text, 50, Range("N1").Text, "BIS", Range("L2").Text
End Sub
Sub button_2_oos_vanh()
    change_stock Range("B2").Text, Range("B3").Text, 0, Range("N3").Text, "OOS", Range("L3").Text
End Sub

Sub button_2_bis_vanh()
    change_stock Range("B2").Text, Range("B3").Text, 50, Range("N1").Text, "BIS", Range("L3").Text
End Sub
Sub button_3_oos_unc()
    change_stock Range("B2").Text, Range("B3").Text, 0, Range("N4").Text, "OOS", Range("L4").Text
End Sub

Sub button_3_bis_unc()
    change_stock Range("B2").Text, Range("B3").Text, 50, Range("N1").Text, "BIS", Range("L4").Text
End Sub


Sub change_stock(looking_for, looking_for2, change_to, change_to_message, inorout, stocktype)
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to put " + looking_for + " width " + looking_for2 + inorout + " as type " + stocktype, vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    For y = 20 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
        If InStr(Cells(y, 7), (looking_for)) > 0 And InStr(Cells(y, 12), (looking_for2)) > 0 Then

            Cells(y, 15) = change_to
            Cells(y, 17) = change_to_message
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi John. Welcome to StackOverflow. If you want to get some help here, you must show that you tried to solve your problem by yourself. Actually, in case of your problem you can do a lot with only a small knowledge. First thing to do is to record a macro. Start recording and do what you described above. Then check the code and try to develop it.

Comment: Hi Egan - thanks for the comment and my apologies. I will ensure I follow the StackOverflow way in any future requests!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John, I've made the assumption you know how to add a button and to assign a macro to run if it's clicked? If so, the code below should do what you're after.

```
Sub button_1()
    change_stock Range("D1").Text, 0 ' set stock value to zero
End Sub

Sub button_2()
    change_stock Range("D1").Text, 50 ' set stock value to 50
End Sub

Sub change_stock(looking_for, change_to)
    ' Loop to look at each cell in column A
    For y = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
        If Cells(y, 1) = looking_for Then ' <- if cell in column A matches looking_for value
            'change the value
            Cells(y, 2) = change_to
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This also makes the assumption there are no gaps in your data, as if this is possible you'll need a different way to decide on where to stop the Y loop.

Comment: Hi CLR,

Thanks for jumping on this quick and looking to help me, it's really appreciated. Just to confirm, so the code you have put will the code you have placed above search within column A for any cell that contains the text in D1, then subsequently replace the column adjacent (B) with either 50 or 0 depending on which button is pressed?

When you say gaps - I assume this is a gap in the data as in maybe A10 is blank?

To give a better example, column A cells may contain for example

Product Name Green Length 100cm Width 70cm

I may want to search for Product Name Green Width 70cm

Comment: Last note -

The process to clarify is enter product to search for in D1, hit button In or Out which searches A1 for text that contains D1 and subsequently changes the stock cell in the B cell adjacent to 0 or 50.

Comment: @John - in that case, with those example entries I'll need to tweak the code. Currently it's looking for a match on the leftmost part of the cell, followed by an underscore (as per your original example). I'll edit my original answer so that the cell has to be an exact match. For that reason, you may want to populate D1 and the table from dropdowns.

Comment: If you don't want an exact match, instead have the program work where the cell *contains* the text in D1, you would replace the IF statement with:             `If InStr(Cells(y, 1), (looking_for)) > 0 Then`

Comment: Thanks again CLR, I have replaced with the If Instr and this works better, I've updated the code to what I'm using in my initial post as in practice the cell ranges are a bit different.

Is it possible to use And for an if instr statement? I'd like to match something in something in A and something in B before updating C. (see my poor attempt at updating the code!) :)

Comment: Please ignore my last comment. The updated code in my original post is working perfectly. @CLR Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have updated my original post with my now live code which is working absolutely fine, thank you - The only flaw however is when I click a button, I have checked and the data is updating fine, but VB is showing Run-time error '13': Type mismatch.

Do you know why this might be? As I say, all the data is updating fine so it doesn't seem like this error is interrupting the code running

Comment: What part of the code is highlighted when the error occurs and you click debug?

Comment: The line debug highlights is 

`If InStr(Cells(y, 7), (looking_for)) > 0 And InStr(Cells(y, 12), (looking_for2)) > 0 Then`

Comment: Try.. `If InStr(Cells(y, 7).TEXT, (looking_for)) > 0 And InStr(Cells(y, 12).TEXT, (looking_for2)) > 0 Then`